# Improve search by omitting "closed as duplicate", "closed as low quality", etc., by default

Tags: feature-request, search, duplicate-questions, low-quality-posts

I apologize if this idea has been brought up before, but if so I couldn't find it because **the search feature is a little hard to use**....  :P

I just did a search on the Unix & Linux stackexchange for "nologin".  The **very first** result which appears is [a duplicate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24758/what-is-the-difference-between-sbin-nologin-and-bin-false) with no answers, a score of -1, and when clicked it shows "merged with ____".

It seems to me that results like these should be omitted from the search results, unless they are specifically included.

I had never actually used advanced search before, but I looked at it just now and it seems to me the *defaults* should be "duplicate:no closed:no".

Adding a way to specify "duplicates and nonduplicates both" would also be indicated, since that would no longer be the default.  I think a syntax for that could be "duplicate:include" or perhaps "duplicate:maybe" to include both duplicates and nonduplicates; likewise "closed:maybe".

Note that historical questions would still be included with the defaults adjusted as I describe, as you can verify for yourself by searching "locked:yes closed:no duplicate:no".

Does anyone else agree with this idea?

An additional (more advanced) possibility when there are "closed as duplicate" questions which match the search criteria, is to perform some behind-the-scenes substitution and return the *good* question, which the duplicate was closed in favor of.  This would allow any keywords present in the duplicate question to act as cross indexes directly to the question they are a duplicate of.  (I hope I explained that clearly.)

Also: **I know the search system needs a major overhaul**, as discussed elsewhere in meta, but the very simple action of changing the default search scope and adding a syntax for "both closed and not closed" would go quite a ways toward improving my daily use experience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I strongly disagree:

- The main reason to keep duplicates at all is that they may be found by people who do not find the target question due to using the wrong keywords. If you find a duplicate of the question that solves your problem (or that you are looking for for other reasons), your search was successful. Even if both, the duplicate and the target are found in a search, you may not recognise the target as what you are looking for from its title and thus the duplicate may be useful.
- Most users of the search arguably look for an answer to their specific problem. If the respective question is not a good fit for the site, finding a similar or identical question being closed may prevent the user from asking it in the first place. Just imagine people asking questions such as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=closed%3ayes) again and again and again.

Comment: Fair enough, although I still think that having the duplicat**ed** question show up in search results in place of the duplicate question could be useful.  But I do understand the argument against it.

Comment: For the record, after some months more experience on stack exchange, I now completely agree with your answer and think my proposal was silly.